Multiple Model Configuration in tensorflow serving
i have created  a file model.config for configuration detail and it is inside model_config and  model_config is inside untitlled folder from where iam executing my script and getting the path not found error while passing configuration file
!docker run -p 8500:8500 
-p 8501:8501 
--mount type=bind,source="C:\Users\ASUS\building-machine-learning-pipelines\Untitled Folder\my_housing_model",target=/models/my_model 
--mount type=bind,source="C:\Users\ASUS\building-machine-learning-pipelines\Untitled Folder\model_config",target=/models/model_config 
-e MODEL_NAME=my_model 
-t tensorflow/serving  --model_config_file="building-machine-learning-pipelines/Untitled Folder/model_config/model.config" 
--model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
if anyone could help me to understand path dependecies , i will really appriciate

The issue you're facing with Docker and paths is likely due to how paths are interpreted differently between Windows and Unix-like systems (which Docker containers use). In your Docker command, ensure that you're using forward slashes / for paths, even on Windows. Docker commands expect Unix-style paths, even when executed on Windows.Make sure that the paths you provide to Docker are absolute and correctly point to the directories where your model and configuration files reside.

Avoid spaces in your directory names and paths, as they can sometimes cause issues in command-line environments. If you must use paths with spaces, make sure to properly enclose them in quotes (").
